# Модули и локальные пакеты

Tags: golang

Не пойму, почему я не могу обратиться к функции пакета который лежит в папке internal.
Замечаний с стороны компилятора нет, при вызове получаю ошибку - *"package command-line-arguments
cmd\main.go:5:2: use of internal package test/internal not allowed"*
Если переименовать папку *internal* проблема уходит

> Структура проекта

```
test
├─ go.mod
├─ internal
│  └─ handler
│     └─ opkg.go
├─ main.go
```

> main.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    i "test/internal/handler"
)

func main() {
    v := i.GetDouble(15)
    fmt.Println(v)
}
```

> opkg

```
package internal

func GetDouble(a int) int {
    return a * 2
}
```

> go.mod

```
module test

go 1.18
```

Comment: `package internal` заменить на `package handler`

Comment: @E_K, в файле *opkg* заменил  `package internal` на `package handler` проблема осталась

Answer (score 2):

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    s "test/internal/handler"
)

func main() {
    log.Println(s.GetDouble(15))
}
```

test/internal/handler/opkg.go

```
package internal

func GetDouble(a int) int {
    return a * 2
}
```

У меня все работает, ошибок никаких нету

Вывод:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138424/discussion-on-answer-by-----).

Answer (score 0):

Так работает корректно `go run .`